# Show Treeview frm Database On formload and Add childs , sub Childs ...?

Tags: c#, treeview

i want to show TreeView in this Form ... 
[image]

```
    private void DatabaseToTreeView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        {
        String connectionString = @"String here";

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();


            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select CourseName from Course", connection);

            SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
             //Parent NODE-1
            TreeNode prntnode = new TreeNode();
            prntnode.Text = "Courses";
            prntnode.ImageIndex = 0;
            prntnode.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
            this.treeView1.Nodes.Add(prntnode);
             while (reader.Read())
            {
              prntnode.Nodes.Add(reader["CourseName"].ToString());
            }
            SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand("Select BranchName from Branch INNER JOIN Course on Branch.CourseCode=Course.CourseCode", connection);
             //SqlDataReader reader1 = comm.ExecuteReader();
             // treeView1.ChildNode.Clear();

             TreeNode ChildNode = new TreeNode("BranchName");
             // ChildNode.Tag = "BranchName";
             //ChildNode.Text = "BranchName";
             ChildNode.ImageIndex = 1;
             ChildNode.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
             //treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(ChildNode);
             prntnode.Nodes.Add(ChildNode);
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 ChildNode.Nodes.Add(reader["BranchName"].ToString());
             }

            comm.Connection.Close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: wanna show Treeview frm Database on Form Load
Help me to generate Code ... !!! 
i don't know how to add Child's n sub Child's to Parent Node .

Comment: Please post the code you're having trouble with or some part of the code you do not understand.

Comment: I can see one related question on the right already that looks useful without scrolling down. I'd imagine a little bit of research will provide a quick answer

Comment: @Neel Before you generate Code, you write it. ;) To be more constructive. Nobody here is going to write code for you. You need to provide what you have tried.

Comment: i'm new here ,, don't know where to Post code ?? :(

Comment: @Leri: huh i searched so many tyms on google n write codes bt codes nt working :(

Comment: @Leon: i just post d Code ... plz check it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create `Nodes`. You can add a child node to the Nodes collection of the parent. Here is a small sample but you will have to adapt it:

```
var treeView = new TreeView();
var node = new TreeNode("Node 1 Display Name");

// if you are using entity framework or an ORM it might be helpful to add a reference to the object
node.Tag = myDataObject;
treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
```

I would recommend you build the tree from down up since it is easier if you have all the data you need. The `TreeNode` type has a `Nodes` property as well. You can use the same approach as with `TreeView.Nodes`.

Comment: thanx Moslem :)

i'll try dis ...!! :)

Comment: You are welcome :) If the answer is helpful you should accept it, tick the green check.

Comment: :)
I am new to C#.net and My Programming Skill Is Very Weak.. 

i'm trying dis ,,n  will tick the "green check" very sOon :)